# How to solve sonar stopped on Docker compose Linux

Tags: docker-compose, sonarqube

This runs on Ubuntu 20.4(WSL)

This picture is docker-compose. yml file

[image]

then, I run command `docker compose up`

This Result sonarQube is stoped.

```
bill@bill:~/sonar$ docker compose up
```

[+] Running 2/0
✔ Container postgresql  Running                                                       0.0s
✔ Container SonarQube   Created                                                       0.0s
.
.
.
SonarQube   | 2023.05.12 13:26:20 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
SonarQube exited with code 0

the values with the following commands :

```
bill@bill:~/sonar$ sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=524288
sysctl -w fs.file-max=131072
ulimit -n 131072
ulimit -u 8192
sysctl: permission denied on key "vm.max_map_count", ignoring
sysctl: permission denied on key "fs.file-max", ignoring
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use "sudo before the command"

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=524288
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).